# CMake Error while installing ROS2 packages with colcon

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the colcon tutorial: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Colcon-Tutorial/.

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros2/ros2/master/ros2.repos
vcs import ~/ros2_ws/src < ros2.repos
colcon build --symlink-install
```

I got an error message below.  How would I fix it? Thanks.

```
 Starting >>> fastrtps
--- stderr: fastrtps                                             
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
/home/zhfu/ros2_ws/src/eProsima/Fast-RTPS/src/cpp/ASIO_INCLUDE_DIR
   used as include directory in directory /home/zhfu/ros2_ws/src/eProsima/Fast-RTPS/src/cpp

---
Failed   <<< fastrtps   [ Exited with code 1 ]
Aborted  <<< ament_copyright                                

Summary: 17 packages finished [4.84s]
  1 package failed: fastrtps
  1 package aborted: ament_copyright
  1 package had stderr output: fastrtps
  209 packages not processed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310967/cmake-error-while-installing-ros2-packages-with-colcon/) by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 186 on 2018-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That sounds like you're missing a dependency or two. Have you installed all the system dependencies for installing from source?

https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Linux-Development-Setup

In particular the `libasio-dev` package, but you should make sure all the dependencies are available.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on 2018-12-18**:
Yeah. Thanks. Missing libasio-dev. The colcon document did mention it.

**Comment by [suab321](https://answers.ros.org/users/43390/suab321/) on 2019-06-23**:
Thanks!! worked for me